# urxvt cursor shape set to |

Tags: vim, terminal

I want a cursor set as `|` in vim when in insert mode (it's easy in gnome-terminal, but I want to switch to urxvt). I don't find a good way (`_` is possible, but I really prefer `|` ). I'm sure that all is possible in urxvt with a little bit of imagination.

Is there a way you know (or just an idea) ?

Comment: How do you do it in gnome-terminal?

Comment: In my .vimrc :

if has("autocmd")
 au InsertEnter * silent execute "!gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Profile1/cursor_shape ibeam"
 au InsertLeave * silent execute "!gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Profile1/cursor_shape block"
    au VimLeave * silent execute "!gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Profile1/cursor_shape block"
    endif

Basically, I just need a command to set the cursor in urxvt, but it seems impossible for now.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally DEC didn't provide an I-beam cursor, just a solid block or underbar, via the `DECSCUSR` sequence (`CSI Sp q`):

```
CSI 1 Sp q  == blinking block
CSI 2 Sp q  == solid block
CSI 3 Sp q  == blinking underbar
CSI 4 Sp q  == solid underbar
```

Recently in `xterm` we extended this enumeration to define

```
CSI 5 Sp q  == blinking vertical bar
CSI 6 Sp q  == solid vertical bar
```

It may be possible to suggest `urxvt` adopt a similar encoding scheme.

Comment: It seems very difficult to suggest anything to urxvt... I cannot find a github or somewhere that look likea place to bug report things.

Comment: xterm's changelog says that Paul Bolle provided the patch which began the vertical bar ([patch #282](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_282)).  I don't see Evans as a contributor to explain the "we".